# Can be create ADA compliance web e-store Using NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite

The importance of The American Disabilities Act (ADA) in the eCommerce and IT vertical has become prevalent and super critical with the 2010 amendment of the ADA act. Organizations have started realizing the opportunity of compliance and the consequences of non-compliance.

Can be create ADA compliance web e-store with 2.0 Level AA compliance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya you can create any kind of webstore in netsuite. You will have to purchase the suitecommerce module from netsuite to do this task.